# What is the use of @property (nonatomic, retain) statement in the application ?

Tags: iphone

i m a beginner iphone developer and i want to know about what is the use of @property (nonatomic, retain) statement with example , any body can give me any answer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the point of @property and @synthesize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169822/what-is-the-point-of-property-and-synthesize)

Answer (score 12):

**@property** tells Objective-C to generate the getters and setters for this member variable when it is **@synthesize**'d in the implementation class. The **retain** parameter says that the generated setter should pass the **retain** message to the parameter being set. **nonatomic** means that atomicity of getting and setting the variable is not guaranteed.

Comment: This is an utterly useless answer.

Answer (score 5):

Apple has a lot of examples in the Declared Properties section of their [Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) guide. Definitely worth reading through.